# uniq terminal command doesnt work?

Tags: linux, bash, shell, unix, terminal

I'am trying to learn how to use the terminal command `uniq`. I'am using mac, bash shell (unix).

this is my textfile "terminal.txt":

```
this is a line  
this is a line  
this is a line

this is also a line  
this is also a line 

this is not a line
```

I found an example on using uniq here http://www.computerhope.com/unix/uuniq.htm so this is how I intended using the command. I have not copied the text I wrote it manually into the textfile. However when I type:

```
uniq terminal.txt
```

I get this error message:

```
uniq: terminal.txt: Illegal byte sequence
```

after some googling I found that I should write LC_ALL=C in front of uniq:

```
LC_ALL=C uniq terminal.txt
```

But when I type this I get this output:

```
??t
```

This is not the correct output. I don't know what I'm doing wrong, I can't find a answer on google either.

I there anyone out there who know what I'm doing wrong?

update:

this is the result of `od -c terminal.txt`:

```
0000000  377 376   t  \0   h  \0   i  \0   s  \0      \0   i  \0   s  \0
0000020       \0   a  \0      \0   l  \0   i  \0   n  \0   e  \0      \0
0000040   \n  \0   t  \0   h  \0   i  \0   s  \0      \0   i  \0   s  \0
0000060       \0   a  \0      \0   l  \0   i  \0   n  \0   e  \0      \0
0000100   \n  \0   t  \0   h  \0   i  \0   s  \0      \0   i  \0   s  \0
0000120       \0   a  \0      \0   l  \0   i  \0   n  \0   e  \0  \n  \0
0000140   \n  \0   t  \0   h  \0   i  \0   s  \0      \0   i  \0   s  \0
0000160       \0   a  \0   l  \0   s  \0   o  \0      \0   a  \0      \0
0000200    l  \0   i  \0   n  \0   e  \0      \0  \n  \0   t  \0   h  \0
0000220    i  \0   s  \0      \0   i  \0   s  \0      \0   a  \0   l  \0
0000240    s  \0   o  \0      \0   a  \0      \0   l  \0   i  \0   n  \0
0000260    e  \0      \0  \n  \0  \n  \0   t  \0   h  \0   i  \0   s  \0
0000300       \0   i  \0   s  \0      \0   n  \0   o  \0   t  \0      \0
0000320    a  \0      \0   l  \0   i  \0   n  \0   e  \0  \n  \0        
0000336
```

and this is the result of  `file terminal.txt`:

```
terminal.txt: Little-endian UTF-16 Unicode text
```

and `cat terminal.txt`:

```
??this is a line

this is a line 

this is a line


this is also a line 

this is also a line 


this is not a line
```

Comment: How did you create terminal.txt? What is the result of typing `file terminal.txt` at the prompt? If you type `cat terminal.txt` do you see what you expect, just the file contents like you show above or anything else as well?

Comment: `od -c terminal.txt` may get a good picture of the contents of the file

Comment: @Ed makes a good point, if you can add the output of running `od -c terminal.txt` to your question it will likely help yourself or others understand the source of the issue, since there's nothing inherently wrong with the input or commands shown in your question.

Comment: I have edited the question now with the different commands you commented, but I am still confused, I am not sure what I see from this?

Comment: thank you for your replies btw! 
(small sidenote: I don't have anything, no newline, space or charachter over all  before the first "this is a line" in the text file).

Comment: I guess you have saved this file as unicode with BOM. Load it back into notepad++ and set the correct settings. Re=save

Comment: ``uniq`` works fine, your input data is broken

Comment: Thanks Pebba the additional information you provided in your question made it clear what the source of your problem is, I've created an answer which should help clarify.

Comment: thank you for all your help!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your file is encoded in UTF-16 which uniq isn't able to handle.

To convert the file to UTF-8 which it can, do the following:

```
iconv -f utf-16 -t utf-8 terminal.txt > terminal2.txt
```

The uniq command should then work on your newly created file.

In order to resolve this going forward you should work to understand your editor settings and change them so your files are stored as UTF-8 instead of UTF-16.

You may also want to get familiar with the simple editors you can run on the command line such as vi/vim, emacs, or nano, although these editors take some getting used to at first. These editors generally create simple text files which won't have the problems caused by the editor you used to create your file.